# Listening to serial port to know whether modem installed/removed in C#?

Tags: c#

How will i continuous listen to COM for detecting modem.
if a modem is added or removed it should inform you that Modem installed or removed at COM45 etc.

I have tried to use a thread and check the com count but i am unable to know which com is modem.

If there is any specific class for this pls help me fr the code asap???

Comment: I need to head out, but try a search on WMI and Win32_SerialPort which may help.